# Download .dmg file in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, applescript, dmg

How can I download and open a .dmg file using cocoa or applescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [NSURLDownload or NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html). Google also [answers the question handily](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=cocoa+download+file&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) if you leave out the "dmg" part and go more generic.

Comment: well the big thing is is that it has to open the DMG file

Comment: Matt S.: Downloading a file and opening a file are separate tasks with separate solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As @Joshua said, you can use NSURLDownload or NSURLConnection to retrieve the file.  To mount it, run an `NSTask` that executes `hdiutil attach /path/to/downloaded/file.dmg`.

Comment: Ouch. Seems a bit heavy-handed. Is there some advantage to using hdiutil versus opening the file with NSWorkspace?

Comment: A quick test shows that, where UI is needed (the case of a password-protected dmg), you'd need to interact with the task to supply the password. Via NSWorkspace, you're prompted in the GUI as when opening with Finder.